# execute command in firebug after change of url

Tags: javascript, console, automation, firebug

I am trying to execute a small piece of javascript on a URL, then set a 10 second interval timer to change URL and load another page and then execute that same piece of code...
but after the new page loads, the script stops... is there a way to keep the script running on a global level ? 
or possibly an alternative solution that can provide me with the same result? maybe an automation software that is free and allows this?
I want to startup on this as part of testing scenario but I'm new to this

this is my code that I'm putting in the console
I would like to run the getStuff on the 1st loaded page, then redirect,  then run it again on the 2nd page

```
function getStuff(){   
    var innerHtml = document.getElementById('carInfo').innerHTML;
    console.log(innerHtml);
}
function redirect() {
    location.href = http://localhost/details.php?id=2; // go to 2nd page, want to increment the id as next step
    setTimeout("getStuff()",5000); // wait 5 seconds to load, run getStuff
}


getStuff(); // getStuff() the 1st time (current open page)
var interval = setInterval("redirect()",10000); // redirect() after 10 seconds to a new url then getStuff...loop on this
```

Comment: The purpose is not quite clear, but maybe you could create a greasemonkey script. Such a GM script would be injected on all pages you specify (e.g. for a certain domain) and could provide you with the "carInfo" on every page.

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of this is? It seems as if you are trying to achieve something using the wrong technologies, but without context it's hard to say.

Comment: thanks for your comments
well basically the issue is we're trying to upgrade an old car sales system that has a web based interface, but the source files are not accessible nor is the database (lost passwords or client is in issue with original developer)
so we're trying to extract the information by doing an automated script that can go through all the pages (ids) and save the html of the info part ... so till we hopefully get access to original files, we're trying to test this automation method and try to gain time

if there's an automation software that can do the same, would also work fine

Comment: (we cannot edit/read the source files, they've been encrypted, otherwise it would have been easy)

Comment: I would recommend using an automation plugin like iMacros: http://www.iopus.com/imacros/. It can take in a collection of URLs and scrape them easily. I've had a lot of success using it.

Answer (score 0):

You have these choices:

1. Use AJAX to load the pages. That way, you are not leaving the page that ran the script.

   ```
   getStuff -> AJAX GET -> Append to page -> getStuff -> AJAX GET ....
   ```
2. Call getStuff and redirect on every page you intend to load. You can also use a cookie to indicate that you need to run that "reloader" on that page.

   ```
   cookie set -> getStuff -> redirect -> read cookie -> if cookie ok -> getStuff -> redirect...
                                          '--> if not ok -> stop
   ```

Comment: thanks, will also check into that 
main issue is that we cannot edit/read the source files (for cookies)